# Active Directory for Windows Web Server 2008?

Tags: active-directory

Is there a way to get AD LDS for Windows Web Server 2008 (not 2008 standard) ? If not would old ADAM version work ?

Comment: We need A whole lot more info on what you are doing or trying to accomplish to be able to help you

Answer (score 3):

Web Edition can be a member server, but no DC. As LDS is a replication-related service, I'd say no. Also, as google tells me, ADAM wouldn't work either.

Comment: Are you sure that ADAM cannot be installed ? Finally I found this http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397383%28EXCHG.80%29.aspx To install ADAM to the Windows Server 2008 operating system

Comment: I'm not _sure_ as in I've tried myself, but ADAM and "Web Edition" (2003) doesn't.

Comment: OK I'll try and will tell you ...

Comment: It says "not enough storage ..." when launching which is completely fake :(

Comment: you don't need to be a DC to run AD LDS but there are other limitations on web edition that would prevent LDS or ADAM from functioning- as Zypher mentioned we still don't have any details or what exactly is trying to be accomplished here

Comment: @JimB: You don't need to be a DC, but you must access and install replication-related services, which are not available on a Web Edition